# Maven eclipse plugin: Use linked or virtual folders as source folders

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

I am using the maven-eclipse-plugin (not M2E!) to generate my project. I have checked out the project under a source directory: C:\source, and this source is not organized in the Maven convention. My eclipse work space is under C:\eclipse\workspace, where I have the POM files.

In the POM, I have specified to create linked / virtual folders to organize the source in the Maven format (src/main/java, etc):

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <linkedResources combine.children="append"> 
            <linkedResource>
              <name>src</name>
              <type>2</type>
              <locationURI>virtual:/virtual</locationURI> 
            </linkedResource>
            <linkedResource>
              <name>src/main</name>
              <type>2</type>
              <locationURI>virtual:/virtual</locationURI> 
            </linkedResource>
            <linkedResource>
              <name>src/main/java</name>
              <type>2</type>
              <locationURI>WORKSPACE_LOC/source/mymodule</locationURI>
            </linkedResource>
          </linkedResources>
          ...
        </plugin>
```

When I create a project for eclipse by running `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`, the `.project` file hence generated has linked folders (or virtual folders):

```
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>src</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>virtual:/virtual</locationURI>
    </link>
    <link>
        <name>src/main</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>virtual:/virtual</locationURI>
    </link>
    <link>
        <name>src/main/java</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>WORKSPACE_LOC/source/mymodule</locationURI>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

but the `.classpath` file generated does not add those folders to the classpath as source folders for my project, i.e., an entry like the following is missing:

```
<classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
```

If I were to create a project using eclipse (and not using the maven-eclipse-plugin), I could create virtual / linked folders as necessary and add them as source folders to the project.

Using the plugin, I am forced to point to the absolute path to the source folder as sourceDirectory. The plugin does not seem to recognize linked / virtual folders and hence does not add them as a source folder to my project. Is there a solution for this where I can add a linked folder as a source folder to my eclipse project generated using the Maven eclipse plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, to be clear, does your source in version control have a POM file and can be built with `mvn clean install`? I was confused by your comment "*My eclipse work space is under C:\eclipse\workspace, where I have the POM files.*"

Comment: No, the source from SCM is separate from the Mavenized project. So there is no POM under _italic_C:\source_italic_, it only has the source code. The POMs are located in the Mavenized project in the work space.

Comment: Wow, that feels a highly convoluted approach. Have you considered adding a POM to the source code and just running `eclipse:eclipse` there? Some effort would be required to get the POM to accept the non-standard hierarchy, but it should be doable. Then the invocation of `eclipse:eclipse` would be "normal" and you could just import the existing project into your Eclipse workspace using the menus.

Comment: Hmm, no, the source cannot be mavenized at this point of time, hence the search for a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following approach?

1. Check out source (including existing POM file) to `C:\source`.
2. Open Eclipse to workspace `C:\eclipse\workspace`.
3. Select **File > Import... > Maven > Existing Maven Projects**
4. Navigate to the directory containing your `pom.xml` file and proceed to import.

This works for me on projects where I keep the source and workspace paths completely separate.

Comment: But when I import the project, there is no source attached to it. Do I not need to manually configure the source folders then?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. Does your Maven project follow the [standard project layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)? My answer also assumed you have an *existing* `pom.xml` file (which builds fine from the command line).

Comment: No, the source does not follow the standard layout either, which is why I wanted to create virtual folders as per the standard layout. As an example, the source module is like: /source/module/java-package, which when I import as a source folder would be like: module/src*/main*/java*/java-package - where *: virtual folder. It might not be possible at this moment to re-structure the source, hence the problem.

Comment: Interesting. Does the project currently build OK with Maven from the command line (`mvn clean install`)? If so, then you've presumably configured your POM correctly to cope with the non-standard layout. In that case, I think you're best to raise a bug against m2e as it ought to handle any Maven project which can be built in a standard fashion on the command line.

Comment: I guess this might be confusing, but when I say eclipse plugin, I do not mean the m2e plugin for eclipse. I mean the maven-eclipse-plugin. Now to answer your question, I have been running eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse from the command prompt and there I see the problem. The thing is when the plugin generates the .project file, it correctly creates the virtual folders, but in the generated .classpath file, it does not have any references to the virtual folders as source.

Comment: My mistake, sorry I went off on the wrong tangent. I don't know the answer off hand. Any chance you could post a little `pom.xml` and suggest a project layout so that I can test this? I would add that to the main question so that others can experiment.

Comment: I updated the question while you were posting the comment. :) Let me know if the update helps. Thanks for your time!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17562/discussion-between-neel-and-duncan-jones)